# ShareLatex - PDF disappeared

Tags: pdf, sharelatex

I'm using ShareLatex and sharing a code with my workgroup in real time. The problem is that I clicked a button on the gutters and I used to have the code on the left and the pdf on the right and I could compile the PDF whenever I wanted. Now, since I clicked the button, the PDF disappeared from the right and I only see the screen as in the image. How can I view the code and PDF again?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please do not paste code as images, but as code.  Make sure to add compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Then it will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Bobyandbob My goal is not for me to correct the code. It works fine. My goal is that I would like to know which buttons to click on to appear the code on the left and the PDF (which I can compile) on the right. It used to look like this before. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but i do not use sharelatex. I think it would be a good idea to ask [sharelatex help](https://www.sharelatex.com/).

Comment: There should be a grey vertical bar on the right side of the page with an arrow on it, click that.

Comment: Please consult this documentation in ShareLaTeX help Center https://es.sharelatex.com/learn/Kb/Can%27t_find_the_PDF_viewer